# Contiki sky-shell-exec symbols.o error (symbols.o):(.rodata.symbols+0x6): warning: internal error: out of range error

Tags: arduino, contiki

I am trying to run the **sky-shell-exec** example in Arduino Yun.

I have finished defining the platform details and **cfs-coffee-arch**. But when i try to run **sky-shell-exec**. I ger an error.

When i just make sky-shell-exec.arduino-yun. It is ok. But then i try to make `sky-shell-exec.arduino-yun CORE=sky-shell-exec.arduino yun`, the same options as `TMOTE-SKY`. I get an error.

```
ERROR: contiki-arduino-yun.a(symbols.o):(.rodata.symbols+0x6): warning: internal error: out of range error
contiki-arduino-yun.a(symbols.o):(.rodata.symbols+0x4a): warning: internal error: out of range error
contiki-arduino-yun.a(symbols.o):(.rodata.symbols+0x56): warning: internal error: out of range error
contiki-arduino-yun.a(symbols.o):(.rodata.symbols+0x132): warning: internal error: out of range error
contiki-arduino-yun.a(symbols.o):(.rodata.symbols+0x13a): warning: internal error: out of range error
contiki-arduino-yun.a(symbols.o):(.rodata.symbols+0x21e): warning: internal error: out of range error
contiki-arduino-yun.a(symbols.o):(.rodata.symbols+0x22e): warning: internal error: out of range error
contiki-arduino-yun.a(symbols.o):(.rodata.symbols+0x232): warning: internal error: out of range error
contiki-arduino-yun.a(symbols.o):(.rodata.symbols+0x25a): warning: internal error: out of range error
contiki-arduino-yun.a(symbols.o):(.rodata.symbols+0x27a): warning: internal error: out of range error
contiki-arduino-yun.a(symbols.o):(.rodata.symbols+0x2b2): warning: internal error: out of range error
contiki-arduino-yun.a(symbols.o):(.rodata.symbols+0x32a): warning: internal error: out of range error
```

Can someone give me help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Arduino is not a platform ported in Contiki, at least in the official Contiki repository (perhaps on some developer's branch).

Comment: Thank you. I get it but i want to do some work on Yun. I think it may be very interesting.